# .net core 2.0 change injected middleware settings at runtime

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Hope my question will be clear. ;-)
Is it possible to change Middleware settings during runtime? I explain more.

I have following code in my configure services method in an Asp.net core 2.1 webapi

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
                if (!securitySettings)
                {
                  options.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
                }
```

I would like to add that filter depending on a setting in the database. Is it possible to change that during runtime or do i really need to restart my application after that setting has been changed?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own MiddlewareFilter that does your custom logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't modify the filters applied to MVC after the application has started.

However, MVC has the concept of [authorization requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1#requirements), which are executed on each request. That makes them a great candidate for what you're trying to achieve.

On a high-level, we will:

- change the default authorization policy to include a custom requirement;
- create the class that *handles* this requirement, that is, determines if it's satisfied or not

---

Let's create the requirement class. It's empty as it doesn't need any parameters, since the result will come solely from the database:

```cs
public class ConditionalAnonymousAccessRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

Then we create the class that handles this requirement:

```cs
public class ConditionalAnonymousAccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ConditionalAnonymousAccessRequirement>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public ConditionalAnonymousAccessHandler(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ConditionalAnonymousAccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (IsAnonymousAccessAllowed())
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsAnonymousAccessAllowed()
    {
        // Implementation based on the value retrieved from the database
    }
}
```

The implementation is straightforward. If we find in the database that anonymous access is allowed, we mark this requirement as succeeded. If at least one of the requirements in a policy is satisfies, then the whole policy succeeds.

---

The next step is to add that requirement to the authorization policy. By default, when using an `[Authorize]` attribute with no parameters, MVC uses the default authorization policy, which [just checks that the user is authenticated](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/beaa2b443d46ef8adaf5c2a89eb475e1893037c2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationOptions.cs#L22-L28). Let's modify it to add this new requirement in the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup` class:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddRequirements(new ConditionalAnonymousAccessRequirement())
        .Build();
});
```

---

All looks good, but we're missing one final piece.
While we added the requirement to the policy, we haven't registered the requirement handler, which [is necessary for MVC to discover it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1#handler-registration). This is again done in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```cs
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ConditionalAnonymousAccessHandler>();
```

While the documentation shows the handler is registered as a singleton, in this case it's better to register it per-HTTP request as it has a dependency on a `DbContext` which are by default registered per-HTTP request. Registering the handler as a singleton means an instance of DbContext would be kept alive during the whole application lifetime.

Please let me know how you go!